# Why does this prepared statement always return -1 rows affected?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm having a lot of trouble with this mysqli prepared statement and I can't figure out what the problem is. I've done a ton of troubleshooting already, so to start I'll just show you the code (as you can see, it's just working locally for the moment):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbName");

if($stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO created_memes (created_meme_fileName, created_meme_title, created_meme_likes, created_meme_datePosted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")){
    $stmt->bind_param('sssd', $fileName, $title, $likes, $datePosted);

    $title = $_POST["memeTitle"];
    $likes = 0;
    $dataPosted = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


    $stmt->execute();

    printf($stmt->affected_rows);

    echo "Link established; query unsuccessful.";

    $stmt->close();

} else {
    echo "Link unsuccessful.";
}
```

Just to briefly go over this:

The $fileName variable is defined earlier in the code, so that's not the issue. Even if it was, I've tried redefining it with the rest of the variables, and I still get -1 rows affected.

I've tried setting all the variables to static strings, just in case there was a problem with them, but it still doesn't work.

I've quintuple-checked the connection info, table name, and column names; they are all correct.

I've tried this both as the if statement you see now, and without the if statement. Still doesn't work.

I've tried it with bind_param BEFORE the variables are defined, as you see now, and also AFTER they're defined, hoping that might matter. It didn't. Still didn't work.

At this point I've torn out all my hair and am still no closer to finding the problem. Any assistance at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Oh for the sake of holy hell... datEposted, not datAposted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php):

```
-1 indicates that the query returned an error.
```

Try `echo $stmt->error;` to see what went wrong

I'll hazard a guess that it's because you specify 4 fields by name to insert into, then provide 5 piece of data to insert.

Comment: Err, well, yes, I do know that -1 means an error, which I suppose I didn't make clear. WHAT IS the error would be a better question. I didn't know you could echo it out like that though, so I'll check it out.

Comment: It'll likely be that you're missing a field name in the list.